# Accessing a associative array

Tags: javascript, associative-array

Im trying to create a function that allows us to enter a persons name and their age. It will then be saved into an array.

```
var personnes=[];

function ajoutePersonne(n,a){
    personnes["Nom"]=personnes.push(n);
    personnes["Age"]=personnes.push(a);
    personnes["Enfant"]=""; 
}
ajoutePersonne("Julie",100);
ajoutePersonne("Sarah",83);
ajoutePersonne("Jennifer",82);
ajoutePersonne("Olivia",79);
ajoutePersonne("Marge",55);
ajoutePersonne("Mathilde",48);
ajoutePersonne("Joanne",45);
ajoutePersonne("Isabelle",47);
ajoutePersonne("Celine",23);
ajoutePersonne("Caroline",29);
ajoutePersonne("Wendy",24);
ajoutePersonne("Kaliste",26);
ajoutePersonne("Karine",22);
ajoutePersonne("Sophie",28);
ajoutePersonne("Orianne",25);
ajoutePersonne("Alice",21);

print(personnes[1].Nom);
```

How come when im trying to access the 2 second person in the array under the category "Nom", Nothing shows up.

Comment: `personnes["Nom"]=personnes.push(n);` --- what this weird line means?

Comment: This is not an associative array. _Associative array_ means an array whose index is a name that you want to look up, instead of being index numerically. In Javascript, associative arrays are implemented using objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put an entire object in the array, not push the name and age seperately:

```
var personnes=[];

function ajoutePersonne(n,a){
    personnes.push({ "Nom" : n, "Age" : a, "Enfant" : ""});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

personnes is an array, so in javascript it can only have integer indexes.

To do what I think you want to do:

```
function ajoutePersonne(n,a){
    var person = {nom: n, age: a, enfant: ""};
    personnes.push(person);
}
```

Where "person" is a javascript object using JSON.

Comment: I don't mean to be nitpicking, but some of your statements are not entirely correct: 1) Array can as well have non numeric members, but they are not accounted as regular array index 2) There is no such thing like "javascript object using JSON", what you mean is the object literal notation - JSON is a data notation format using to the javascript object literal notation as base.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are only meant to store numeric indices, you can create members like `Nom` but these will in no way react like a normal numeric index.*

Either use an object, or push objects into your array.

```
var personnes=[];
personnes.push({ "Nom" : "Julie", "Age" : 100 });
personnes[0].Nom // -> Julie
```

or

```
var personnes={};
personnes["Julie"] = 100;
// equal to:
personnes.Julie = 100;
```

or

```
var personnes={};
personnes["Julie"] = {"age":100 /*,"more attributes":"here"*/}
```

However, the last two notations assume that the names are unique!

*You can do the following:

```
var ar = [];
ar.attr = 5;
ar.attr; // -> 5
ar.length; // -> 0, since attr is not enumerable
// also all other regular array operation won't affect attr
```